# Snowflake: what is the APPADMIN role?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

I was just looking through our account roles (using `SHOW GRANTS ON ACCOUNT`) to identify an issue with some privileges, when I ran into an unknown role: `APPADMIN`.

This role does not appear along with the other system roles (`ACCOUNTADMIN`, `SYSADMIN`, `USERADMIN`, `SECURITYADMIN`, `ORGADMIN`, and `PUBLIC`) when I look at the full list of roles in the account (either in the UI, or using `SHOW ROLES`). I'm using the `ACCOUNTADMIN` role, so everything should be there.

Also, when I run `SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE APPADMIN`, it fails: `SQL compilation error: Role 'APPADMIN' does not exist or not authorized.`

Moreover, how can this role have any grants if it apparently doesn't exist? I tried creating and dropping a dummy role, and the grants were dropped along with the role (as expected).

```sql
CREATE ROLE test;
GRANT CREATE DATABASE ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE test;
SHOW GRANTS ON ACCOUNT; -- test grant is there
DROP ROLE test;
SHOW GRANTS ON ACCOUNT; -- test grant is no longer there
```

The role has access to `CREATE DATABASE`, `CREATE INTEGRATION`, `CREATE ROLE` & `CREATE USER`, and the grants were added on `2020-06-05`.

We've never created this role, so I assume it must be some kind of system role -- maybe something related to [Snowsight](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight.html)?

Can anyone else also see this in their account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct these operations were part of our automated feature provisioning for Snowsight which needed to perform some specific operations when it launched in Public Preview between 6/4/20 and 6/5/20.  Given these operations were internal, it should not be viewable on our customers' end.  We'll get this corrected and thanks for bringing to our attention.